# Composer Installation on Server

Tags: php, composer-php

How do I install composer on my web server? Is it a directory that I need to include?

I don't understand where the below code goes:

```
curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer
```

From:
https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md

Comment: which type of server do you have ? like afaik you can not install composer on shared hosting/server

Comment: @NullPoiиteя You can't install it to `/usr/local/bin`, but you can install it for just your own user if you have SSH access.

Comment: Its a web server from godaddy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The command `curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php` gets the code located on `https://getcomposer.org/installer` and sends it to PHP, PHP then runs the code on the given page.  The code on that page will produce a composer.phar file in your CWD.

The command `mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer` moves composer.phar to be file `/usr/local/bin/composer`

see:

- [mv](http://linux.die.net/man/1/mv)
- [curl](http://linux.die.net/man/1/curl)

These are Linux commands and are meant to be ran on a Linux server.

Comment: So do I put the above code in a PHP file? Where do I run the "curl" statement from?

Comment: These are Linux commands and are ran from the Linux command line.

Comment: Do I have to request command line access on shared hosting? Where can I find the command line on godaddy

Comment: Thx, just connected via Putty